# Mapping complex JSON to a List in MVC Action argument

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have classes like this

```
public class someList
{
   public string strOne {get; set;}
   public string strTwo {get; set;}
}
public class Entity
{
    public string EntityMember;
    public List<someList> entityList;
}
```

Then I have a controller and action,

```
public ActionResult MyControllerAction(Entity objEntity)
```

How to post the form from browser with JSON data so that it maps with my Entity object. Here is my currenct javascript function for submitting the form,

```
function submitForm() {
    var Entity = {};
    var eList= new Array();

    eList[0] = { strOne: "91", strTwo: "12" };
    eList[1] = { strOne: "92", strTwo: "12" };

    Entity = { EntityMember: "Member Value", entityList: eList };
    $.post("/MyController/MyControllerAction", Entity);
}
```

But it is not working. I am able to get the value of EntityMember but the List object does not come.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is for asp.net mvc? if it is , which version are you using?

Comment: ASP.net MVC 2. By the way, why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is for asp.net mvc 3, entity needs to be stringfied

```
$.ajax({                                                    
        url: "/MyController/MyControllerAction",                                       
        type: "POST",                                           
        data: JSON.stringify(Entity),                          
        dataType: "json",                                       
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
        success: function (data) {                              
            ....                                     
        }                                                       
    });
```

if this is for asp.net mvc 2, you will also need to register the json provider, please reference this [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

The reason yours doesn't work is that jquery's built-in serialization format has been changed http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

you will need to either set it to use traditional way:

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

or use a different serialization method. (In above, I used stringify function for JSON binding, part of JSON.org's json2.js)

Comment: I am using mvc 2. Do i need to download and update my Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll with the futures library ??

Comment: you could try jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; (just use Entity, don't stringify it), it probably will work, it would use model binding by default. The one I described above is for JSON binding.

Comment: By the way, I am not doing AJAX request. I am doing $.post(). Will this work in that case "jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true"